# Lombok @Builder with setter

Tags: java, lombok

I have class having Lombok `@Builder` annotation as

```
@Builder
public class Employee {

  private String empId;
  private String empName;
  private String managerName;
}
```

After processing or after some business logic I want set managerName in same Employee Object by using `setter` method like `empObj.setManagerName("managerName")`

How can I use setter method with Builder in Lombok

Answer (score 4):

You have options. Check out [the Lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter)

**If you want just `managerName` to have a setter:**

Use the Lombok `@Setter` on `managerName`, i.e.

```
@Setter
private String managerName;
```

**If you want all your fields to have a setter:**

> You can also put a @Getter and/or @Setter annotation on a class. In that case, it's as if you annotate all the non-static fields in that class with the annotation.

You can also add [the class-level `@Data` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data). It gives you the combined effect of several other annotations, and is often useful for POJO's.

**NB** that `@Data` and `@Builder` play a little rough with one-another, because `@Data` removes the default no-arg constructor. So, if you want to keep `@Builder`, you'll need to add an explicit `@NoArgsConstructor`.